# SSL Client Server Handshakeexception: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl

This is a sample client server program with ssl in java.
We are getting an exception when the client sends data to the server. The server
stops after printing the exception. Please help.

My Server code

```
package SSLExample;


import java.security.Security;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;



import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;


import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;





public class SSLServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        try {
            
//          System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
// we are just getting and printing all the providers that's all not related to server.         
            Provider [] provider = Security.getProviders();
            
            System.out.println("provider size : "+ provider.length);
            
            for(int i =0; i< provider.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("provider name :"+provider[i].getName());
                System.out.println("provider info :"+provider[i].getInfo());
                
                System.out.println("provider to String :"+provider[i].toString());
                System.out.println("========================================");
            }
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");  // for more details visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore       
            
            
            String password = "abcdefg";
            
            InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/SSLExample/server-certificate.p12");
            
            keystore.load(inputStream,password.toCharArray());
            
            //TrustManagerFactory()
            
            
            String password2 = "aabbcc";
            
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX","SunJSSE");
            
            InputStream inputStream2 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/SSLExample/client-certificate.p12");
            trustStore.load(inputStream2,password2.toCharArray());
            
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            
            X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = null;
            
            for(TrustManager trustManager: trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers())
            {
                if(trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager)
                {
                    x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if(x509TrustManager == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            
            // KeyManagerFactory()
            
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509","SunJSSE");
            
            keyManagerFactory.init(keystore,password.toCharArray());
            
            
            X509KeyManager x509KeyManager = null;
            
            for(KeyManager keyManager: keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers())
            {
                if(keyManager instanceof X509KeyManager)
                {
                    x509KeyManager = (X509KeyManager) keyManager;
                }
            }
            
            if(x509KeyManager == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            

            SSLContext sSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sSLContext.init(new KeyManager [] {x509KeyManager},new TrustManager [] {x509TrustManager},SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong());
            
            
            
            SSLServerSocketFactory sSLServerSocketFactory = sSLContext.getServerSocketFactory();
            
            SSLServerSocket sSLServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(8333);
            
            sSLServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
            
//          sSLServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(
//                    new String[] { "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" });
            
            sSLServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String [] {"TLSv1.2"});
            
            SSLSocket sSLSocket = (SSLSocket) sSLServerSocket.accept();
            
            //InputStream and OutputStream Stuff
            
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(sSLSocket.getOutputStream(),true); //out
            
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sSLSocket.getInputStream()));  //in
            
            String inputLine="hello";
            
//          printWriter.println();
            while(true)
            {
                
                System.out.println("data: "+ bufferedReader.readLine());
                
                if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            
        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

My Client Code

```
package SSLExample;


import java.security.Security;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;



import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;


import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;





public class SSLServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        try {
            
//          System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
// we are just getting and printing all the providers that's all not related to server.         
            Provider [] provider = Security.getProviders();
            
            System.out.println("provider size : "+ provider.length);
            
            for(int i =0; i< provider.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("provider name :"+provider[i].getName());
                System.out.println("provider info :"+provider[i].getInfo());
                
                System.out.println("provider to String :"+provider[i].toString());
                System.out.println("========================================");
            }
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");  // for more details visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore       
            
            
            String password = "abcdefg";
            
            InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/SSLExample/server-certificate.p12");
            
            keystore.load(inputStream,password.toCharArray());
            
            //TrustManagerFactory()
            
            
            String password2 = "aabbcc";
            
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX","SunJSSE");
            
            InputStream inputStream2 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/SSLExample/client-certificate.p12");
            trustStore.load(inputStream2,password2.toCharArray());
            
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            
            X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = null;
            
            for(TrustManager trustManager: trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers())
            {
                if(trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager)
                {
                    x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if(x509TrustManager == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            
            // KeyManagerFactory()
            
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509","SunJSSE");
            
            keyManagerFactory.init(keystore,password.toCharArray());
            
            
            X509KeyManager x509KeyManager = null;
            
            for(KeyManager keyManager: keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers())
            {
                if(keyManager instanceof X509KeyManager)
                {
                    x509KeyManager = (X509KeyManager) keyManager;
                }
            }
            
            if(x509KeyManager == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            

            SSLContext sSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sSLContext.init(new KeyManager [] {x509KeyManager},new TrustManager [] {x509TrustManager},SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong());
            
            
            
            SSLServerSocketFactory sSLServerSocketFactory = sSLContext.getServerSocketFactory();
            
            SSLServerSocket sSLServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(8333);
            
            sSLServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
            
//          sSLServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(
//                    new String[] { "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" });
            
            sSLServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String [] {"TLSv1.2"});
            
            SSLSocket sSLSocket = (SSLSocket) sSLServerSocket.accept();
            
            //InputStream and OutputStream Stuff
            
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(sSLSocket.getOutputStream(),true); //out
            
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sSLSocket.getInputStream()));  //in
            
            String inputLine="hello";
            
//          printWriter.println();
            while(true)
            {
                
                System.out.println("data: "+ bufferedReader.readLine());
                
                if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            
        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Commands used for generating certificates

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out client-certificate.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out server-certificate.pem

openssl pkcs12 -inkey client-key.pem -in client-certificate.pem -export -out client-certificate.p12
openssl pkcs12 -inkey server-key.pem -in server-certificate.pem -export -out server-certificate.p12
```

Error got during in the server

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:294)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHello.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1091)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:843)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:802)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1417)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:922)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1013)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:181)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
    at SSLExample.SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:149)
```

This is the exception that we are getting Do we need to add anything for cipher suite. is there anything missing in the code.
please help.

Comment: I am stuck on this issue for a day.

Comment: no cipher suites in common means that server and client can not agree on which cipher to use because there is no intersection both sides support (and that fits to the server key type). Modern servers mostly use EC keys, may be this error happens because you use RSA key pair. What Java version do you use on client and server side?

Comment: How to fix it. what we need to change in the code.

Comment: The java version is java 8

Comment: Which JVM are you using?some of the older oracle JVMs have limits  and will require the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~20.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I am not sure about JCE can you guide me

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't start a new project using Java 8. Even if it is an LTS release with is supported for many years it is quite old. IMHO you should better start with Java 17 (also LTS). This will save you work later as you don't have to migrate client and server to a newer Java release.

Comment: We are still getting the exception in java 17 also

Comment: This may mean that the server can't find its certificate.

Comment: I case of cipher problems you can run test tools like https://testssl.sh to see what ciphers your server supports.

Comment: (@user207421) in particular, check that the `getResourceAsStream` calls are returning nonnull; if the server keystore _resource_ isn't accessible, the keystore _object_ and thus the KeyManager will be empty, and the server won't be able to support any of the usual protocols. PS: are you sure you're running 8? Your posted stacktrace is from a modulized version (9 up).

Comment: (@dave_thompson_085) To be even more particular, if the server can't find its certificate the only cipher suites it can use are the anonymous ones, which are normally, and rightfully, disabled: so when it comes to choose from the intersection of its own enabled cipher suites and the client's, the intersection set is empty, so there are 'no cipher suites in common'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by creating a different folder for server and client in the resource folder and placed there certificate there.

Works in eclipse and command line (java 17)